# IndexError on my Battleships strategy in python

Tags: python

When running my strategy in the battleships program, I receive an IndexError: list index out of range. The code works fine for most of the squares on the map but on the squares close to the outline of the map such as when row = 0 the error appears. 
My battleships strategy picks random moves on the map storing each guess in the lastHit list outside the function. If a guess hits a ship, then next turn, row and col will take the last two values in the lastHit list and then check the adjacent squares around it using the criteria set in the if statements. The error code appears on line 10 where the first if statement is.

```
lastHit = [1, 1]

def chooseMove():

    global playerBoard, opponentBoard

    row = lastHit[0]
    col = lastHit[1]

    if (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) and (opponentBoard[row - 1][col] != opponentBoard[5:][:5]) and (row - 1 != -1):
    row -= 1
    if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT)) and (opponentBoard[row + 2][col] != opponentBoard[5:][:5]) and (row + 2 != 12):
        row += 2
        if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT)) and (opponentBoard[row - 1][col - 1] != opponentBoard[5:][:5]) and (col - 1 != -1):
        row -= 1
        col -= 1
            if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT)) and (opponentBoard[row][col + 2] != opponentBoard[5:][:5]) and (col + 2 != 12):
            col += 2
            if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT)) and (opponentBoard[row][col] != opponentBoard[5:][:5]):
                while (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED):
                        row = randint(0,len(opponentBoard)-1)
                        col = randint(0,len(opponentBoard[row])-1)
                else:
                    lastHit[0] = row;
                    lastHit[1] = col;
                    return row, col
            else:
                lastHit[0] = row;
            lastHit[1] = col;
            return row, col 
        else:
            lastHit[0] = row;
            lastHit[1] = col;
            return row, col
        else:
        lastHit[0] = row;
        lastHit[1] = col;
        return row, col
        else:
        lastHit[0] = row;
        lastHit[1] = col;
        return row, col
    else: 
        while (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED):
            row = randint(0,len(opponentBoard)-1)
            col = randint(0,len(opponentBoard[row])-1)
        else:
        lastHit[0] = row;
        lastHit[1] = col;
        return row, col
```

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that and will edit it in now. It's on line 10 where the first if statement is.

Comment: It seems like you're not making sure your indexes are within bounds by the time you access them. Just by assuming `row = 0`, it's obvious you're going to run into trouble when trying to access `[row - 1]`. if `lastHit[0]` is `0` you've got a guaranteed out-of-bounds error. You _do_ check later, but by that time, you've already acceessed the index and python's going to have trouble. Check for `row - 1 >= 0` or something to that effect _before_ you ever use `row` or `row - 1` as an index and it should work. edit- after the indentation fixed it's clearer, but I think my comment holds.

Comment: In the future, indent large blocks of code by selecting the whole block and clicking the `{}` button, not by trying to mark each line as code one by one. I've fixed this one for you.